# Alert keeps popping up when on focus out

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a grid in which user can add as many rows as he wants and there are two textboxes (Minimum Value & Maximum Value). When the user enters Min and Max value. I am checking whether the range that user has entered is already there in the database. if yes then it shows me an alert. I am doing this on `focusout` Now the problem is that the alert keeps popping up infinite times when I click from one textbox directly to another textbox. Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the function on my focus out

```js
function CheckValidation(obj) {

  var ajx = new AJAXsupport();
  ajx.resetVar();
  ajx.addData('CL', 'CheckValidation');

  var sucSave = function() {
    if (ajx.getRefreshText() != "0") {
      alert(ajx.getMessage());
      $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      return false;
    } else {
      $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', false);
    }
  }
  customSave(ajx, sucSave);
}
}
```

Comment: Is `getRefreshText()` supposed to return the `0` as a string or as a number, when the range is not already in DB?

Comment: Basically when the range does not exist in the DB, this ``getRefreshText`` becomes 0. So Iam only showing alert when it is not 0. Also this is supposed to return the string "0"  @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Any idea?

Comment: Console log what really is returned... Try the code from this [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/WXz53w6C)